# AWS Collaboration on a Project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So, I am working on a project where I will need to use tons of services that AWS has to offer like S3, EC2, Route53, Textract, RDS and some more. However, during the course of the project, I am going to be collaborating on the project with my team.

I know I would set up an IAM User for everyone on the team. But, how do I assure that everyone has access to the services mentioned above so that we can work on the project together?

Comment: By setting up multiple users / roles / single-sign one, etc.

Comment: *"how do I assure that everyone has access to the services mentioned above so that we can work on the project together?"* - e.g. by giving everyone `AdministratorAccess` or something similarly powerful. Depends on your actual use case and a lot more context information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. Make sure you have one root account and enable MFA on it. Then go to IAM and create a user yourself. Try to change the 12321312.signin.aws.com link to yourTeamName.signin.aws.com for easy logins too.

Once you create a user for yourself, go to the side on IAM and click groups. Create a new group called "admins". Click next and then attach the administratorAccess policy. [AWS Img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqkKH.png) Then click next. Then save it. Then click on your group, and then click "add users to group" and select the user account for yourself that you just made.

Now, log out of the root account and log into your name@projectNameRootAccount and you can do everything that you did on your root. Only difference is you are not coding on your root and it is safe from hackers.

Next.... to make it extremely simple.... You could just create a user under IAM for each of them and add them to your admins group.

Best practice would be to give them less privileges but if it is an informal thing.... not a big deal. I would consider clicking on their IAM names from time to time and click on the access advisor tab to see what services they are actually using. If they are only using "dev" type things, you can see that pretty clearly within a week or so and then you can go and create a new group for "devs" and then just give them the policies you see under "access advisor (when you click on their IAM name)". [image: access advisor]

Then you can take them out of the admins group and give them the access that they truly need.

Thanks and good luck with AWS. It can be complicated haha.